# Download package into stream and push into Nuget

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-2.0, nuget-package

I'm downloading the package from Nuget.org and then pushing it into local reository. I want to push the package into local repository directly from nuget.org. I don't want to download into temp folder. I'm wondering how can I use stream here.

```html
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/EntityFramework' -OutFile "C:\NugetPS\Temp\EntityFramework.nupkg"

Nuget push "C:\NugetPS\Temp\EntityFramework.nupkg" -Source 'C:\NugetPS\LocalNuGetPackagesServer'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your local Nuget server is storing the packages on the hard drive. In principle, you can save it directly to the hard drive of your local server, or you will have to reverse engineer the Nuget Push protocol.

Comment: It's just the sample code. I'm running the copy of Nuget.org to host local repository. So I need to push the package into the repository.

Comment: You can still share a folder. Otherwise, you will have to implement a web request to push the stream to server.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Script above works fine, only issue is it download to intermediate location and then push to local repository. I want it to directly push to local repository.